# Parse a File for "ERROR", write index of found record to a new file as a key. Use file of keys to search first file for records

Tags: perl, file, logging, hash, big-o

[upate: Are there Perl file manipulation functions/methods that I am not seeing here?]

I was given a Perl problem for an interview. I believe I gave an answer to the problem, but not the "brain teaser" answer they wanted. So, I relearned Perl to code up and test my answer compared to theirs. My Perl is not strong so I am not sure if I coded their solution the best way. I want to be fair to them (I still think my solution is exponentially faster.)

Problem: Scan a log file that contains log entries that are multi lined.

```
01 BEGIN 
01 some text 
02 BEGIN 
01 more Text 
01 END 
02 other text 
02 END 
03 BEGIN 
03 even more text 
03 ERROR
...
```

Find the error records and write the entire record to a new file. Above example would produce:

```
03 BEGIN 
03 even more text 
03 ERROR
```

in the new file. The log entries/records that end with "END" are not in the new file.

Constraints: You can't read the entire file in at one go. You have to read one line at a time due to file sizes and memory constraints.

Their solution:

They specifically did not want to read the key file fully into memory as a constraint. 
Scan the log file for every occurrence of "ERROR". If found then write the "index" number, 03, to a new file as a key. This file of keys will be used next.

```
03
```

Rescan the log file matching index numbers in the log file to keys in the key file.

Where I am stuck and need help is how to do their solution more efficiently.

I read the first log file in one line at a time to get a log entry index.
  I then read the key file one line at a time to get a key.
    I then did an 'eq' on the index and the key

```
    if ( $_[0] eq $key )
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

It seems to me this is inefficient. This reads the entire original log file two times.

1. to find the keys
2. to match each log line against each key in the key file

This reads the key file X times for every line in the log file As the number of keys increases, due to error rate, the time it takes to match one log line against more keys grows fast.

if there are 10 keys and 100 lines to read then that is 10*100 key file reads.
if there are 100 keys and 100 lines to read (100% ERROR) then 100*100 key file reads

So, without reading the key file into memory (such as storing keys in a hash), is there a more efficient way to do matching of a log file line to a key?

Is there a way to 'grep' the key file for each line in the key file?
Is there a better way?
If the key file is sorted does that help?
Would there be a file manipulation method I could use to delete/ignore the keys for the records I have already found in END for the log file, so as to continually decrease the size of the key file to only keys I have not found?

Could I duplicate the error log file and key file? Then delete lines from both files that I know are not needed. I could sort the key file. The error log file could be sorted, but the errors are nested/overlapping.

Am I not seeing old school file manipulations with perl?

=====
My solution was to read the log file one line at a time. Then create a queue each time I saw a "BEGIN", to store each set of lines with the same index. The queue would then be put in a hash. A hash of queues of log entry lines.

```
my %queues;
my @logLines; # queue to hold lines in order for later write if needed
push @logLines, $line;

$queues{ $index } = [@logLines];
```

If "END" was read, then I deleted the queue as I would not need to write it out.

if "ERROR" was read, then I wrote out the contents of the queue, deleted the queue

Then deleted the hash entry for the queue.

The result was the "ERROR" blocks being written to a file in proper order. 
No having to write or rematch a key file.
No having to sort the final file.

Against a 10,000 log record file (about 80,000 lines)

```
#error rate     Their       Mine
1:1000          2 secs       2 secs
1:100           4            2
1:10            20           2
1:5             38           2
1:2             79           2
```

that seems wrong to me that my code would:

```
A. Be so much faster
B. Be the same no matter the error rate.
```

Any adults here want to compute O(n) for these?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: The overlapping `BEGIN` and `END` markers ... does it mean that they mark a "section" but the sections can be nested? If those are indeed sections, any info on how large any one section can get?

Answer (score 1):

> This reads the key file X times for every line in the log file As the number of keys increases, due to error rate, the time it takes to match one log line against more keys grows fast.

No, it actually requires only two passes. Once to identify error blocks. Save those in a hash. Then, during the second pass, check the existence of the key in the hash to decide whether to keep the block.

I am guessing that the concern is that the number of lines you need to preserve may be unbounded.

The following assumes you can keep the a lookup table of tasks with `ERROR` status codes in memory. If the number of tasks with errors is also potentially huge, you can replace the simple hash lookup table with an on disk key-value store (e.g. Berkeley DB, `memcache`, [CHI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CHI), [NDBM](https://metacpan.org/pod/NDBM_File) etc):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use autouse Carp => 'croak';

run($ARGV[0]);

sub run {
    my $logfile = shift;

    my $failed_tasks = identify_failed_tasks($logfile);
    print_failed_tasks($logfile, $failed_tasks);
}

sub identify_failed_tasks {
    my $logfile = shift;

    open my $in, '<', $logfile
        or croak "Failed to open '$logfile' for reading: $!";

    my %failed_tasks;

    while (my $line = <$in>) {
        last unless $line =~ /\S/;
        my ($id, $status) = split ' ', $line, 3;
        next unless $status eq 'ERROR';
        $failed_tasks{$id} = undef;
    }

    close $in
        or croak "Failed to close '$logfile': $!";

    return \%failed_tasks;
}

sub print_failed_tasks {
    my $logfile = shift;
    my $failed_tasks = shift;

    open my $in, '<', $logfile
        or croak "Failed to open '$logfile' for reading: $!";

    while (my $line = <$in>) {
        last unless $line =~ /\S/;
        my ($id) = ($line =~ /^(\S+)/);
        next unless exists $failed_tasks->{$id};
        print $line;
    }

    close $in
        or croak "Failed to close '$logfile': $!";

    return;
}
```

Note that the code above assumes you do not have a log file like:

```
04 BEGIN
04 foo
04 bar
04 baz
03 BEGIN
03 even more text
03 ERROR
04 ERROR
```

If that is a possibility, I would consider inserting lines to be printed in an SQLite database, and printing them out with the appropriate `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: That is true that using a hash would speed things up. But their solution was to not use a %hash.  I specifically remarked several times that using hashes would speed up the process. They countered that it would not be needed. That reading the files one line at a time and not saving lines would be okay. My guess is they were trying to do  perl1 > perl2 > perl3 stuff. Or want something they can run in a micro service that would not need hashes.

Comment: Then you need to update your question to clear things up. You say "*Their solution: ... Rescan the log file matching index numbers in the log file to keys in the key file.*" ... Then you describe how you implemented that rescan: "Where **I** am stuck and need help is how to do their solution most efficiently. **I** read the first log file in one line at a time to get a log entry index. **I** then read the key file one line at a time to get a key. **I** then did an 'eq' on the index and the key" ... Nothing is preventing you from reading back just the identifiers into a hash.

Comment: But if there is a constraint of not even keeping that in memory, you can use Berkeley DB or similar for an on disk key-value lookup table, memcache whatever. You don't have to scan the file *N* times, just 2.

Comment: I guess my question then is how to do the matching the keys with one read at a time faster. If I read the larger file in one pass then I read the key file multiple times. If I read the keys file first then match to each line of the larger file the time should be the same? What if I read a line from the log file and then grepped the index against the key file?

Comment: I asked, even suggested that the output goes in a DB. Nope, they wanted just reads. Could I use an index into the key file to exclude keys to records that have been completed?  Could I have duplicated the keys file, then used the duplicate while deleting keys once the record was done so as to decrease the number of keys each time? Could I have run through a duplicate of the original log file and deleted entries that were not in they key file, if the key file had been sorted first? Trying to think of a way to their side with only file manipulation as they suggested.

Comment: My overall goal is to improve my own skills. I could have just claimed victory, but there must be of using duplicate files to delete rows to decrease the sequential re-reads. Any tips on Perl file operations that I don't know?

Comment: At this point, we have a vague problem description, and no real constraint specification, so I feel further speculation is not useful. To top it all, you have wasteful constructs in your code, e.g. `$queues{ $index } = [@logLines];` which make me suspect you may have misunderstood what they said and/or what I am saying and/or I am not understanding what you are saying.

Comment: That's fine Sinan. I am not a Perl guy, I just learned it in a few days to do this. I may have answered my own question in the end. I would still like to look at Perl file manipulation. Being judgemental does not really help though does it?

Comment: I am not being judgemental. I am explaining why your question should be closed as "**Too broad:** Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."

Comment: You can choose to improve the presentation of your question, or you can criticize my comments. I am indifferent as to which one you choose, but one of those actions is bound to be more helpful to you.

Comment: @Vanderdecken  I didn't fully understand the problem as posted.  As I read through comments it became _less_ clear what the requirements (and constraints) were.  The comment you reacted at exactly summarized how I felt about the whole thing. It never crossed my mind that it would be "judgemental."  No need to get sensitive.  Please appreciate that Sinan offered a full and detailed answer (and the right one in my opinion), and engaged in a discussion with you.  I appreciate your effort in posting a detailed question but it ended up unclear to me what exactly you need.